# Splash screen android using phonegap is just showing a blank white screen

Tags: android, cordova

My code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",5000);
    //super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Starting your app...");
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

in config xml:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

<!-- Do not auto hide splash on iOS -->
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
```

But its not showing the splash screen rather shows a white blank screen.
How to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's always better to place the drawable in the theme used by the splashscreen

Comment: Can you please be more specific .